# How define variables in a macro, so that they available for the caller of the macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I want to have a macro dbtest that can be used like this:

```
(dbtest
  (prn test-object1)
  (prn test-object2))
```

test-object1 and test-object2 should be variables which are defined by dbtest (because I need them everytime I use the dbtest macro). "prn" is just an example; I want to use arbitrary code inside the macro.

I tried this:

```
(defmacro dbtest [& body]
  `(sql/with-connection db
     (delete-all-tables)
     (let [~'test-object1 (insert-object "foo")]
       ~@body)))
```

where insert-object is a function that insert something into the DB and returns a the corresponding data structure.

But it doesn't work: I get a "no such var" error

Comment: By the way, I believe the variables you defining are called _anaphora_, like "it" in this sentence: I like chocolate, although it makes me fat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me:

```
user=> (defmacro let-test [& body]
         `(let [~'test-object1 123] ~@body))
#'user/let-test
user=> (let-test (+ test-object1 321))
444
```

Are you sure the problem isn't with the SQL-related calls?

Comment: Thx! You're right, it was a totally different problem; I was just confused by the error. fixed now :-)